# i want system sends email to users every week depending on their date input in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to keep sending emails to users every week depending on user date input in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205195/how-to-keep-sending-emails-to-users-every-week-depending-on-user-date-input-in-r)

I am building a system that allows a user to insert info name, date, and email. I want the system to automatically send emails to its users every 7 days from which they inserted.

here`s my mailer

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"
   def welcome_email(dop)
    @dop = dop
    @url  = "http://example.com/login"
    mail(:to => dop.mail, :subject => "Welcome to My Awesome Site")
  end
end
```

and this is controller:

```
def create
    @dop = Dop.new(params[:dop])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @dop.save
        UserMailer.welcome_email(@dop).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to @dop, notice: 'Dop was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @dop, status: :created, location: @dop }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @dop.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write a rake task and call that task through cron.

For example:

```
task :send_email => :environment do
  Dop.where('last_email <= ?', 7.days.ago).each do |dop|
    UserMailer.welcome_email(dop).deliver
    dop.update_attribute('last_email', Time.now)
  end
end
```

Now set up your machines Cron scheduler to call this Rake task every few minutes to send out emails automatically.

[Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) is a Unix scheduler that executes programs in pre-determined intervals.

You need to edit the crontab file using `crontab -e` and enter something like this:

```
*/5 * * * *  /bin/bash cd <path_to_your_app> && rake send_email
```

The `*/5 * * * *` says that you run it every 5 minutes.

Comment: Then get a real operating system :)
Sorry but deploying applications to a 12 year old OS is not good.

Comment: if @dop.date = date.now - 7.days
then 
send_email

Comment: and where should write it in user_mailer.rb Or in dop controller?

Comment: Sorry Abdulrahman, but I can't do your work for you. The above code answers your question but it still takes some effort on your part to integrate it into your application.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a gem called `whenever`

It does exactly what you want.